# gingerbread slower as froyo but why?

Tags: android, android-2.2-froyo, android-2.3-gingerbread

Ive write a Rubiks Cube solver under froyo. For solving a random cube there will be generate several move - and pruning tables. All of them are save in an Array of type static short[][].

Normaly at first start of the Program under Froyo it will take about 90seconds to solve the Cube and then <3seconds.

Now ive update to gingerbread (2.3.4) and it is 10 times slower. But why? How is it possible? Any reason for this?

thanks..

Answer (score 1):

I assume your goal is to make the app run fast on Gingerbread. Have you done any live debugging (e.g. with Traceview)? That would help identify exactly which methods are taking so long, and isolate the problem a bit more.

Comment: +1 for simply suggesting a proper live debugging/trace. I would also consider changing the project's target and native SDK to see if it makes any difference. It's not clear if the author changed the device to 2.3.4 or really the target.

Comment: Yes my first goal is to make it so fast as it was on android froyo. The Program is the same. I know that the Thread wich generates the tables is the most expensive operation in the program. But that was in Froyo too. Why is it slower then before by the same code?